# django-pytest liveserver settings issue

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

when using django-pytest along with the live server, according to the documentation, the live server setting can be done in these ways:

- in the settings *.py such as:
  `DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS="localhost:12588"`
- in the pytest pytest.ini file:
  `DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS="localhost:12588"`
  (tried as well `DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS=localhost:12588`)

in these both cases, the value was not taken into account and still the first source code defined default localhost:8081 was used.

what worked was following (from CLI):

```
py.test --liveserver localhost:12588
```

I am using Django 1.7 and
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6, pytest-2.8.4, py-1.4.31
[pytest] plugins: django-2.9.1

Does anyone know why the other supported ways of setting are ignored?

Comment: might also want to open an issue in django-pytest repo. sounds like a bug

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/300.